# I want to implement a feature in my code that will randomly pick keys and values from lists to later assign them to a dictionary

Tags: python

Instead of already pre-made dictionary of names as a keys and traits as a values

```
colonists = {
    'john': 'sickly',
    'sarah': 'night owl',
    'bill': 'nudist',
    'eric': 'none'
}
```

I want to randomly pick names and traits from two different lists with names and traits and assign them to an empty dictionary. I've tried doing it myself various ways, but it all didnt go well. I overall looking for advices and tips to improve and optimise my code. Here is a code with pre-made dictionary:

```
import random

colonists = {
    'john': 'sickly',
    'sarah': 'night owl',
    'bill': 'nudist',
    'eric': 'none'
}

events = ['plague', 'day', 'clothes', 'none']
current_event = random.choice(events)

print(f"Current event is {current_event}")

for name, trait in colonists.items():
    if current_event == 'clothes' and trait == 'nudist':
        print(f"{name.capitalize()} is suffering due to having a {trait} trait")
    elif current_event == 'day' and trait == 'night owl':
        print(f"{name.capitalize()} is suffering due to having a {trait} trait")
    elif current_event == 'plague' and trait == 'sickly':
        print(f"{name.capitalize()} is suffering due to having a {trait} trait")
    else:
        print(f"{name.capitalize()} is not suffering due to having a {trait} trait")
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried. We need to see at least one of these efforts which `didnt go well`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just shuffle the list and make a dictionary:

```
import random

names = ['john', 'sarah', 'bill', 'eric']
traits = ['sickly', 'night owl', 'nudist', 'none']

# random shuffle
# as @quamrana mentioned, you only need to shuffle one of them
random.shuffle(names) 
random.shuffle(traits) 

colonists = dict(zip(names, traits))
```

Comment: btw, in general, you only need to shuffle *one* of the lists before the `zip` into a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want the same name to appear multiple times, you could create your `colonists` dict by zipping together uniquely chosen names via `random.sample` and a collection of traits (which may appear multiple times) via `random.choices`.

You could create another dictionary (`trait_affected` in my example), which maps events to associated traits that are affected by that event. This makes it easy to then iterate over all colonists, and then print a message for those colonists who are affected by the current event.

```
import random

names = ("john", "sarah", "bill", "eric", "simon", "george", "larry", "bob")
traits = ("sickly", "night owl", "nudist", "none")
events = ("plague", "day", "clothes", "none")

trait_affected = dict(zip(events, traits))

num_colonists = 4

colonists = dict(zip(random.sample(names, k=num_colonists), random.choices(traits, k=num_colonists)))

current_event = random.choice(events)

for name, trait in colonists.items():
    if trait == trait_affected[current_event]:
        print(f"{name.capitalize()} is suffering due to having a {trait} trait")
```